# How to solve RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1 in Flutter/Dart

Tags: android-studio, csv, dart, flutter-layout

My code is giving me the output what i required but there is one error which i need support to resolve.

RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1

**Below is the csv which i am using:**

german word,german sentence,english word,english sentence

die Ansage,Hören Sie auf die Ansagen.,announcement,Listen to the announcements.

**Here is the code:**

I am getting error on line wher i am calling **csvTable[index1+1][0],**

```
class _CsvState extends State<Csv> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: rootBundle.loadString('assets/questions.csv'),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot,) {
          List<List<dynamic>>  csvTable =
          CsvToListConverter().convert(snapshot.data);
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("A1 German Vocabulary"),
              ),
            body: new TransformerPageView (

              itemCount: csvTable.length-1,
                loop: true,
                viewportFraction: 0.8,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index1) {

                  return new Padding(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: new Material(
                      elevation: 8.0,
                      textStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      child: new Stack(
                        fit: StackFit.expand,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Positioned(
                            child: new Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Container(
                                  child: new Text(
                                   csvTable[index1+1][0],
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 24.0,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                  ),

                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                new Container(
                                  child: new Text(
                                    csvTable[index1+1][1],
                                    textAlign:TextAlign.center,
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 24.0,
                                      color: Colors.black,


                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                new Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 20.0),
                                    child: Divider(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      height: 36,
                                    )),

                                new Container(
                                  child: new Text(
                                    csvTable[index1+1][2],
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 24.0,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        height: 2

                                    ),
                                  ),

                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                new Container(
                                  child: new Text(
                                    csvTable[index1+1][3],
                                    textAlign:TextAlign.center,
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 24.0,
                                      color: Colors.black,

                                    ),
                                  ),

                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                ),

                              ],
                            ),
                            left: 10.0,
                            right: 10.0,
                            top: 100.0,

                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
               // itemCount:811
            ),

          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: The error message means you're indexing into an empty list. Try to figure out which list is empty and why.